Spring Boot 3 ignores @CircuitBreaker
I am learning microservices and trying to implement circuit breaker pattern in one of my microservices. At the beginning i wanted to pick Netflix Hystrix library but after some googling i found out that it is now deprecated and is no longer supported by Spring Boot (CMIIW).
So I opt for Resillience4j library.
I have method in one of the services that imitates the slow run on random call (it runs 11s).
So I want CircuitBreaker to kill the slow running call
The thing is that when i imported all required dependencies Spring Boot 3 just ignores @CircuitBreaker annotation which I put above the target method.
I'm using Spring Boot 3.3.2 and Spring Cloud 2023.0.1
Here is the dependencies i have in my pom.xml
// another deps not connected with the problem

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>resilience4j-spring-boot3</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-resilience4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
</dependency>

And here is the slow running method which is called when of the endpoints is hit:
    private void randomlyRunLong() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt((3 - 1) + 1) + 1;
        if (randomNum == 3) sleep();
    }

    private void sleep() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(11000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @CircuitBreaker(name = "getLicenseByOrgCircuitBreaker")
    public List<License> getLicensesByOrg(String organizationId) {
        randomlyRunLong();

        return licenseRepository.findByOrganizationId(organizationId);
    }

I also tried to configure circuit breaker through application.yaml, but these settings don't bring any effect:
resilience4j:
    circuitbreaker:
        configs:
            default:
                slow-call-duration-threshold: 10s
                failure-rate-threshold: 1
                slow-call-rate-threshold: 1

Here is the screen from Postman
Response in Postman
As it can be seen, there is no interruption from circuit breaker.
I will appreciate any ideas, so if anyone can help i will be grateful
UPD: Here is the response from the /health endpoint after 3 calls of the long running method: Postman response
(P.S. English is not my mother language so SRY for possible mistakes)

Your test results are not very clear, you might be misinterpreting the configuration, with the existing config the circuitbreaker will be activated after the first call which takes longer than 10 seconds, so the consecutive calls should be blocked.

I tried putting sleep() directly in the service method in order to every call run for 11 seconds, but circuit breaker still doesn't work

You have to provide more details, how are you testing it, what do you actually mean by circuitbreaker doesn't work? You can query the current status of the circuit breaker by calling '/actuator/health'. Please share the results.

Ok. By saying "circuitbreaker doesn't work" i mean that i expect some kind of exception (CallNotPermittedException as i can remember) in response to the long running call.
I added response from the /health endpoint to the question

It seems that problem is in my configuration of the circuit breaker beacuse it remains in CLOSED state

@BerkKurkcuoglu I added minimum-number-of-calls setting in my config and now i get desirable exception in console. Anyway thanks for your help!

From your comment it appears that you have resolved your problem. Perhaps you should consider answering your own question in order to help others who may be experiencing similar issues?

So, the problem was in my inattention while writing configuration for the circuit breaker.
minimumNumberOfCalls - Configures the minimum number of calls which are required (per sliding window period) before the CircuitBreaker can calculate the error rate or slow call rate.
I didn't specified this setting in my application.yaml file so it took its default value (100), that's why circuit breaker didn't calculate the error rate or slow call rate.
When i specified desirable value for this setting, everything start working as
I expected.
So, my advice for everyone is to be careful when adjusting your circuit breaker settings and read the official docs
